# Yii2 module is not configured! - Options: configFile are required error - codeception

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Yii2 module is not configured! - Options: configFile are required error,
codeception yii2 error
how to fix the error? I have

```
suites:
    unit:
        #        path: .
        path: common
        actor: UnitTester
        modules:
            enabled:
                # add more modules here
                - Asserts
                - Yii2
settings:
    shuffle: true
    lint: true
    bootstrap: tests/_bootstrap.php
paths:
    tests: .
    output: common/_output
    support: common/_support
    data: common
modules:
    enabled:
        # add more modules here
        #- Asserts
        - Yii2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sort it on own, as did not find answer.
The general modules item setting has to have a form of configuration - the subitem has to be named 'config' instead of 'enabled', to be able to be used elsewhere, eg suites - unit section/file, and refer to the configuration file as provided or generated by basic Yii2 templates

```
modules:
  config:
    Yii2:
      configFile: 'config/test.php'
```

visible in full context

```
suites:
    unit:
#        path: .
        path: common
        actor: UnitTester
        modules:
            enabled:
                # add more modules here
                - Asserts
                - Yii2
settings:
    shuffle: true
    lint: true
    bootstrap: tests/_bootstrap.php
paths:
    tests: .
    output: common/_output
    support: common/_support
    data: common
modules:
  config:
    Yii2:
      configFile: 'config/test.php'
```

[image]